# HTML form: file input from a url

Tags: html, django, file-upload

I would like to allow my users to either upload a file from their computer, or give the url of a file to upload.

Is there a way I can use the HTML file input to achieve both of these? My django backend is easier if the file comes in the POST data.

Comment: Yes, you can use `<input type="file" />` to let user upload files from their comp. No, you cannot use it to specify the url of a file to upload: you can create another input, however, take in the url string with it, and download that file with your server.

Answer (score 1):

No, It is not possible to use the `<input type="file" />` for both the purposes.

File input cannot process a string value.